# Use php webform to request URL

Tags: php, forms, url, redirect, web

First time posting here. 
I have little to no experience with PHP. I do, however, provide simple, basic web design services to small businesses.

I wonder if it's possible for a PHP web form to direct visitors to a URL based on the form's input.

I ask this because I want to start clients off on my own domain when they search for available domain names and end up on my reseller platform's domain, as a result of performing a search.

Having performed a search for 'blablabla' on my reseller platform, I end up at the URL: http://instinct-it.secureapi.com.au/system/domain/domain_register/?domain=blablabla&tld%5B%5D=.com.au&tld%5B%5D=.net.au&tld%5B%5D=.com&tld%5B%5D=.net&tld%5B%5D=.co.uk

Which appears to specify the domain suffix and the domain name itself, as well.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, what?

Comment: I have no idea what kind of code to use to initiate a URL request based on web form input. I am asking here for a little guidance

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be client-side, rather than with PHP. You would need to understand what variables need to be passed in the URL and set the form method to get, action to the appropriate URL.

Comment: what do you mean by "variables that need to be passed in the URL"?

Comment: See all those things in the URL you pasted after the question mark? those are all variable/definition pairs.

Essentially you need to find out what variables need to be passed to the domain registrar site, if they can be passed in the URL (or as a "GET" method from the form) and then build the form with the appropriately named fields.

It's not difficult work for a developer, but at the risk of sounding like a jerk, I'd suggest you consider hiring an actual web developer for this. It sounds like you might be in over your head trying to do it yourself.